# Want to make a link like download?id=**

Tags: php

I wanted to make download links in php.

For an example If i have 2 files in my directory then How do i make the download links like download.php?id=1 or 2 or anything.

So what will be the codes in the download.php file.

Please somebody tell me the codes.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "Please somebody tell me the codes." ... **no**. [ask]

Comment: Sir, I have tried something like this. but it is not working.  <?php
$download_id = (int) $_GET['id']; // 5
$files = array(
    file1.pdf,
    file2.pdf,
    file3.pdf,
    file4.pdf,
    file5.pdf,
    file6.pdf  // This is the file they'll get
);

$filename = $files[$download_id];

// get the file name from your array or database
header('Content-disposition: attachment; ' . filename=$filename);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($filename);
?>

Answer (score 0):

use `$_GET`

example:

```
<a href="download?id=1">link</a>

<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];

if(is_numeric($id)){
$filename = 'file.pdf'; // of course find the exact filename....        
header( 'Pragma: public' ); // required
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: private', false ); // required for certain browsers 
header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );

header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($filename) . '";' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filename ) );

readfile( $filename );

exit;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this:

```
$fileId = $_GET['id'];

// do something with that id and return the file path / name

$path = ""; //server path / file name    
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");    //    
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));        
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$path);    
readfile($path);
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, actually how do i know the id number of the fie? ccould you please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Database IDs

To make it possible to link download using `?id=xx`, you will need database table, that associates database ids and file names.

#### Resolving $_GET

In php, this is how you can get ID sent by user:

```
$id = (int)$_GET["id"];
/*ADD YOUR GET FILE NAME CODE HERE*/
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Size: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);   //Send file to user
```

Comment: Sir, if i have some links then how can i put the links inside the php. But it should open by id. please show me least 2 to 3 links inside the php.

Comment: Another thing is How to make a database.